# Http proxy with Apache camel that allows cookies to pass through

Tags: apache, apache-camel

In Apache camel, I was able to proxy the request to different endpoint using the code below, my question is how can i let the cookies  pass through that are send from the actual endpoint to the client?

```
 <route>
            <from uri="restlet:/hello?restletMethod=GET"/>
            <to uri="http4://sears.com?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
        </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are just headers, so unless you remove them, they'll be passed on. The problem you're encountering is probably due to different domains. You can only set cookies matching your own domain. I see you're proxying to Sears. Unless your app resides on the same domain, it won't be able to set cookies for Sears domain.

Comment: There is a headerFilterStrategy on both restlet and http components. Check that required header are extracted from restlet by placing a log between from and to.

You can fix cookies as told by @veggen using a processor.

Comment: thanks for reply - can you please suggest a way to test this out in my  local? so that i have 2 servers and both running under same domain

Comment: If you run any two application locally, they'll both be bound to localhost (different ports obviously), and thus will reside on the same domain. You can also mess with your hosts file and use a different domain locally. So, you just need to run any cookie-writing application locally and you should be able to test the Camel proxy locally easily.